# Java assignment not working

Tags: java, prepared-statement, variable-assignment, resultset

I have a function which allows user's to log in to the system in a User class. Upon logging in - their forename and surname are retrieved from the databased and stored as private variables in the User class.

```
private String username = "";
private String forename = "";
private String surname = "";

public User(){}

public boolean loginButtonAction(String user, String pass) {
    try {
        String statement = "SELECT PUNAME, PPASS, PFNAME, PSNAME FROM APP.PERSON WHERE PUNAME = ? AND PPASS = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = Main.getPreparedStatement(statement);
        ps.setString(1, user);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Logged in");
            username = user;
            forename = rs.getString("PFNAME");
            surname = rs.getString("PSNAME");
            return true;
        }
        rs.close();
        ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Incorrect login details");
    return false;
}
```

I have public methods within my User class to return these variables.

```
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getForename() {
    return forename;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
```

I am creating a new instance of User within my Main class and method for testing purposes and simply printing the User's forename and surname, after logging in successfuly of course:

```
User u = new User();
u.loginButtonAction("johnny", "arsenal");
System.out.println("Forename: " + u.getForename());
```

The username works fine, but of course that's not being pulled from the database. The result of this is as follows:

```
run:
Logged in
Forename:
```

Here are my database values within APP.PERSON:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: Is the SQL statement actually retrieving any value.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov - No as I honestly do not know how.

Comment: Google and learn to debug

Comment: @Code-Guru No errors, just a print out that shows as follows - Forename:

Comment: Chances are very strong that there's no user with that name and password in the database. But yeah, listen to Nikolay: you'll feel like you've got a jetpack on if you can use a debugger to track these kinds of issues down.

Comment: @Jayamohan - I do not know, how would I check?

Comment: Is it saying "logged in" or "incorrect login details" before the "forename:"?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta There's definitely a user with that name and password as it logs in successfully and I can see the database values too. I will have a look at debugging!

Comment: @paxdiablo Knew I forgot something - it says logged in, I have amended the question, thanks.

Comment: John, take a good look at that final graphic you added. Tell me what the `PFNAME` and `PSNAME` columns contain for `johhny/arsenal` :-) Therein lies your problem, nothing to do with the query, just the DB contents.

Comment: Thank you all - such a silly mistake :) thank you all for your patience and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of debugging, the first thing you should do is replace:

```
forename = rs.getString("PFNAME");
```

with:

```
forename = rs.getString("PFNAME");
System.out.println ("forename set to [" + forename + "]");
```

This will tell you what's being placed into `forname` at the point where it's being placed there.

If that's blank, your problem lies with the data coming out of the database.

---

And, based on your latest update, the `PFNAME` and `PSNAME` columns for `johnny/arsenal` are indeed blank.

So it appears your code is working perfectly, it's just that your database isn't populated as you seem to expect.

The `select` is case-sensitive so there's a difference between `johnny/arsenal` and `Johnny/arsenal`. Perhaps you were thinking you want the uppercase variant, in which case you should use:

```
u.loginButtonAction("Johnny", "arsenal");
```

Comment: Thank you, I get this response - 

Logged in
forename set to []
Forename:

Comment: I think I know why, the data in the database is a Varchar and I am using getString. Should I be using something else? This might possibly be my problem, going to do some fishing around.

Comment: I have tried using getNString as this says in the javadoc that it is used to return Varchar's as Strings - but it breaks the login method completely and does not work!

Answer (score 1):

You have two values in your DB.   One with a capital Johnny and one with a lowercase johnny.

You are querying for the lower case johnny and it does not have a PFNAME or PSNAME value.

Always try to test your SQL before looking into the code.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you all - this has taken me ages and it was a simple mistake with the error right in front of me. Thank you all.

Comment: Many databases (all?) can be configured to log the SQL that is being run against them. It's useful to see what queries your application is running, especially as you can run them independently to see what results will be returned